# Remove a line from a file using ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a file called `authorized_keys`. I need to delete a particular line using an Ansible script.

The problem is when I try to remove a line that includes a '+' character. Ansible is not able to remove this line.

e.g `authorized_keys` file is:

```
 .....
 abhi foo+bar saken
 ......(EOF)
```

I want to remove the `abhi foo+bar saken` line but Ansible is not removing this line because of the `+` character.

I am able to remove lines that do not contain a `+` character .

Task:

```
- name: Delete keys in sysadmin/.ssh/authoriezd_keys
  lineinfile: dest=/home/{{name}}/.ssh/authorized_keys
              state=absent 
              regexp='^{{key}}$'
```

PS: I am using Ansible's `lineinfile` module

Comment: Please show your tasks. Are you on windows/linux/mac?

Comment: I am using linux , I just updated task

Comment: using `lineinfile` is often a sign you'd be better off to write a file, either with `copy` or with `template`. That gives you *full* control of the file, rather than being unsure of its contents.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Even my leader suggest me to do this. Now I am using copy content module, I have full control of the file and it's working too

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are not using a module for this purpose? http://docs.ansible.com/authorized_key_module.html

Comment: Yes, I need to update the authorized keys very frquently. Basically I put cron job of my Flask application . For that I am maintaing database when end_time reached I need to delete one of the keys in authorized file (not file) as well as Database. For that I can't use authorized_key module

Answer (score 12):

The problem probably is that `+` has a meaning in a regular expression.

You should be able to fix it by escaping the `+`. If you can't do that from the source where `{{ key }}` is defined, you can escape it with the [`replace`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#replace) Jinja filter:

```
- name: Delete keys in sysadmin/.ssh/authoriezd_keys
  lineinfile: dest=/home/{{name}}/.ssh/authorized_keys
              state=absent
              regexp='^{{ key | replace("+", "\+") }}$'
```

You might run into more problems if `{{ key }}` contains other characters which have a meaning in regular expressions. If that's the case I think the safe way would be to create your own [filter plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins) where you simply return the input passed through [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape).

Comment: I tried your solution , it is not working for me. Could you please suggest other way to reolve + character problem?

Comment: Can you try with variations of multiple backslashes... funny, can't post backslashes here in the comment section, heh! Try two or three backslashes.